# Is it possible to know which category page the post was linked from?

Tags: categories

For example, I have a post that's filed under category 1 and category 2. When someone clicks on it from category 2, I want to know the slug for category 2. If it links from the category 1 page, I want to know the category 1 slug.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As anything that has to do with stats this is really an analytics task and as such not something that WP does natively.

You options are:

- installing (if not already) some kind of analytics solution and getting data from it
- add code to that post that will track referers (I won't really recommend this since it comes with performance issues and poor caching compatibility)